# Java XML-replace using org.xml.sax.XMLReader

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204219/java-replace-in-xml-file/6258570#6258570) there's an recommendation *"Use a SAX (or StAX) parser and writer at the same time."*. As I understand it, it should combine e.g., a `org.xml.sax.XMLReader` with some XML-writer, my problem is that there seem to be many of them and none fits exactly to the `XMLReader`. Ideally, I'm looking for something capable of both

- accepting the arguments as they come from `startElement` and `endElement`
- writing an arbitrary XML-containing string

The name of the factory class for the writer is probably sufficient for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing exactly what you want to do, but have a look at David Megginsons XMLWriter: http://www.megginson.com/downloads/xml-writer-0.2.zip

It is an XMLReader and you can easily extend it to accomplish what the other answer implies: i.e use your extended XMLWriter as an XMLreader in a filetered set up.

Comment: First I wanted something what can be fed directly with what I get from the XMLReader, then I've found out that I want to preserve the formatting... I'm afraid I'll stay with regexes. But +1 for the interesting link.